# How can we access the value of row with the help of another row sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have table with 3 fields.
I want to extract the col_value corresponding to type and amount and put it in as a seperate column type and amount. How do i do that? 
Given below is the table.

```
ID  | col_name |    col_value
1   | type     |    abcd
1   | amount   |    1234
2   | type     |    adcd
2   | amount   |    224
```

and the result i want from sql query is

```
type | amount
abcd | 1234
```

Comment: given that there is no relationship between those rows - the answer is you don't. can you put in more sample rows into the table? is it always id, id + 1 that you want to display side by side?

Comment: there was a small error in the above given table. The id is same for both. I mean it is repeated for type and amount.  
ID  | col_name |    col_value
1   | type     |    abcd
1   | amount   |    1234
2   | type     |    defg
2   | amount   |    124
3   | type     |    dfds
3   | amount   |    4121

Comment: that's not a small error, that's a giant gaping question breaking error :D

Comment: Do you use both MySQL and MS SQL Server here? Don't tag products not involved!

Comment: @jarlh yes. I wanted to solve for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN col_name = 'type' THEN col_value END) AS type,
    MAX(CASE WHEN col_name = 'amount' THEN col_value END) AS amount
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY ID
```

You could add a `WHERE` clause to specify which `ID` you want to return.

---

As ughai commented below, it'll be better to keep to `GROUP BY` clause to account for multiple `ID`s.

Comment: Even if he needs to return a single `id`, I would suggest on keeping the `group by id`. Tomorrow if that changes to an `IN (1,2)` problems will start

Comment: @ughai, agree! I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @wewesthemenace thank you for your help. It worked exactly the way i wanted.